# Retrofit Log for outgoing POST request does not match incoming packet

Tags: java, django, post, retrofit

I am trying to send a POST request to my remote Django server via Retrofit. I have created a log for the RestAdapter for Retrofit but when I monitor the log, I notice that the request is being sent correctly as POST:

```
---> HTTP POST http://[omitted IP]/users/login_user/?username=Lucas&platform=AND&client_version=1.0
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 18

password=abcd12345
---> END HTTP (18-byte body)
```

but it is received on the server (according to tcpdump) as a GET request.

I can send essentially the same request using curl:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" -d 'password=abcd12345' "http://[omitted IP]:22800/users/login_user/?username=Lucas&platform=AND&client_version=1.0"
```

and this results in a POST request being received by the server, which it processes correctly.

Here is the POST packet from tcpdump via curl:

```
05:54:25.849761 IP [omitted IP].dsl.teksavvy.com.53549 > 192.168.0.150.22080: Flags [P.], seq 1:251, ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 9311380 ecr 191199659], length 250
 E...;.@.8.cQE........-V@a./.........f9.....
 .....ey.POST /users/login_user/?username=Lucas&platform=AND&client_version=1.0 HTTP/1.1
 User-Agent: curl/7.32.0
 Host: [omitted IP]:22800
 Accept: */*
 Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
 Content-Length: 18

 password=abcd12345
```

and what I would think should be pretty much the same packet (but isn't) from tcpdump via Retrofit:

```
05:57:40.801738 IP [omitted IP].dsl.teksavvy.com.55429 > 192.168.0.150.22080: Flags [P.], seq 1:320, ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 45578792 ecr 191219119], length 319
E..s.g@.8...E.........V@.h...........i.....
..z(.e..GET /users/login_user/?username=Lucas&platform=AND&client_version=1.0 HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
User-Agent: Dalvik/1.6.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.2.1; Galaxy Nexus Build/JOP40D)
Host: [omitted IP]:22800
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 18
```

Where could the packet be changed? Are packets recorded in tcpdump after potentially being modified by the application layer? Or is Retrofit lying and actually sending a GET request? Any ideas on how to debug this problem further would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you ever found a solution to the problem? I'm having a similar issue with retrofit and appengine..

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem by changing endpoint url from: `endpoint-address.com` to `www.endpoint-address.com`. That's it the server redirect from www-less address seemed to screw the POST requests.

Comment: That's interesting. Right now I'm just using an IP address but I wonder if it would work if I got a www domain and used that.